# How to access switch results of a case?

Tags: swift

How does one access the switch statement result of the example apple swift book code?

I guess I could make function that just returns the value of the case statement but I am trying to understand this code.

```
enum ServerResponse {
    case Result(String, String)
    case Error(String)
}

let success = ServerResponse.Result("6:00 am", "8:09 pm")
let failure = ServerResponse.Error("Out of cheese.")

switch success {
case let .Result(sunrise, sunset):
    let serverResponse = "Sunrise is at \(sunrise) and sunset is at \(sunset)."
case let .Error(error):
    let serverResponse = "Failure...  \(error)"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is so contrived that it's not at all helpful.  Consider this

```
enum ServerResponse {
    case Result(String, String)
    case Error(String)
}

for i in 1...100 {
    let mySuccess: ServerResponse = {
        let zeroOrOne = rand() % 2
        if zeroOrOne == 0 {
            return ServerResponse.Result("7:00 am", "8.09 pm")
        } else {
            return ServerResponse.Error("Out of cheese.")
        }
    }()

    var serverResponse: String
    switch mySuccess {
    case let .Result(sunrise, sunset):
        serverResponse = "Sunrise is at \(sunrise) and sunset as \(sunset)"
    case let .Error(error):
        serverResponse = "Failure... \(error)"
    }

    println(serverResponse)
}
```

The gist is that the 'success' variable in the example should really be an assignment as a result of some function / subsystem call.  I wrapped it in a loop for println() clarity

Comment: Cool, but why use the inline close style to assign `mySuccess` and not `serverResponse`?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to declare your `serverResponse` variable outside of the switch code block:

```
var serverResponse: String

switch success {
case let .Result(sunrise, sunset):
    serverResponse = "Sunrise is at \(sunrise) and sunset is at \(sunset)."
case let .Error(error):
    serverResponse = "Failure... \(error)."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's just an incomplete example.

You would normally do something in the case blocks that has a visible effect to the outside (and not just assign it to a local variable that cannot be accessed outside of the switch block).

Note that you can of course access `sunrise`, `sunset`, `error` and `serverResponse` in the case blocks themselves.