# Understanding enum and function signature

Tags: macos, swift

In learning Swift, I came across this code: -

```
enum ServerResponse {
    case Result(String, String)
    case Error(String)
}

for i in 1...10{
    let mySuccess: ServerResponse = {
        let zeroOrOne = rand() % 2
        if zeroOrOne == 0 {
            return ServerResponse.Result("7:00 am", "8.09 pm")
        } else {
            return ServerResponse.Error("Out of cheese.")
        }
    }()

    var serverResponse: String
    switch mySuccess {
    case let .Result(sunrise, sunset):
        serverResponse = "Sunrise is at \(sunrise) and sunset as \(sunset)"
    case let .Error(error):
        serverResponse = "Failure... \(error)"
    }

    println(serverResponse)
}
```

As can be seen here, there are parentheses () after the closing end brace of the declaration for:

```
let mySuccess: ServerResponse = {
  ...
}()
```

Without the parenthesis, playground produces the error:-

> Function produces expected type 'ServerResponse'; did you mean to call it with ()?

Considering a function has the signature: -

> func name(param) -> returnType

Can someone please explain why the parenthesis are required here? Is it a form of minimised closure, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an anonymous function/lambda/closure (however you want to call it exactly), taking no argument, and whose return type is inferred by the compiler, which is then called immediately. It's similar to `(function() {…})()` in JavaScript.

It has the big advantage of allowing you to define `mySuccess` as a constant instead of a variable. Additionally, it creates a scope, such that intermediary variables (like `zeroOrOne`) are not visible outside.

What I'm wondering is just why the author of this code didn't use the same style to define and assign `serverResponse`…

Comment: Thanks Jean-Phillipe. Would there ever be a need to pass an argument here, since the closure has access to variables outside of its own scope? As for the author of the code using the same style, it was taken from the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226167/how-to-access-switch-results-of-a-case

Comment: Indeed, no need for arguments, as code inside the closure will automatically capture everything referenced from the outside world. It effectively acts as a local scope.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's much clearer now ;O)

Answer (score 2):

Your `ServerResponse` is not a function, it is an `enum`, but without the parentheses the block you would be trying to assign to `mySuccess` IS a function (that returns a `ServerResponse`), and therefore cannot be assigned to a `ServerResponse`. The result of calling the function (adding the parentheses) can be.

Comment: I know ServerResponse isn't a function. I see what you're saying; using the parenthesis ensures the closure is executed, rather than the compiler interpret it as being assigned to the LHS variable.